# arranging controls accordiong to div height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have controls in a webpage within a div, my requirement is to arrange the controls according to div height i.e., when there is a change in div height the controls should rearrange according to height

this sounds simple but any help is greatly appreciated

```
<div class="messagepop pop" id="firstpop" style="width: 250px; display: block;border:4px solid #aaa">
<a class="search-choice-close" onclick="closeRsltDiv('contact','firstpop')"     href="javascript:void(0)" style="float:right;font-weight:900;">X</a>
<div id="div_result_holder" class="chzn-container chzn-container-multi chzn-container- active" style="height:100px;width:248px;overflow-y:scroll;border:2px solid #aaa">
<ul id="merch_drp_div_ul" class="chzn-choices"></ul>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Clear All" onclick="clearSelected('merch_drp')">
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnid" class="btn" value="Change Size" onclick="changeSize('firstpop')">


$('#btnid').click(function(){
    //alert("hai");
    var somediv = document.getElementById("firstpop");
    somediv.style.height = "500px";
});
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or a working site where I can see what you are talking about?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/pakuP/](http://jsfiddle.net/pakuP/)
here is the jsfiddle example, when you click the button "change size" the outer div changes but i want that change to effect inner controls, i mean the inner controls should arrange accordingly

Is there a way to catch change in div height event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dynamically resizing the innerdiv by an 80% height value as well.

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/pakuP/4/

Comment: yah this works fine but the problem is its changing the scroll functionality of the inner div, example [http://jsfiddle.net/pakuP/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/pakuP/2/)

I mean if the innerdiv exceeds some size the scroll should appear

Comment: sry i dont see any change in d answer